# How to pivot column values of the below table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

TableA:

```
Brand     Product
------------------
A            X
A            XX
A            XXX
B            Y
B            YY
C            Z
```

I need data as shown in Table below:

```
A      B      C
-------------------
X      Y      Z
XX     YY     NULL   
XXX    NULL   NULL
```

How to do that in Sql Server 2008 ?

Comment: What's the relationship between `X`, `Y` and `Z`? That is, could the first row be `XXX`, `YY`, `Z` instead?

Comment: X, Y, Z are not related to each other, its just representation that I have to show in one of my reports. Yes first row can be XXX, YY, Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont beleive a PIVOT is what you are looking for here.

From what I can see you are looking at using the entries in order to generate the rows?

Also, PIVOTs make use of aggregate functions, so I cant see this happening.

What you can try, is something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Brand VARCHAR(10),
        Product VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','X '
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','XX' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','XXX'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B','Y' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B','YY' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'C','Z' 

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Brand ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RID
        FROM    @Table
)
, RIDs AS (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                RID
        FROM    Vals
)
SELECT  vA.Product [A],
        vB.Product [B],
        vC.Product [C]
FROM    RIDs r LEFT JOIN
        Vals vA ON  r.RID = vA.RID
                AND vA.Brand = 'A' LEFT JOIN
        Vals vB ON  r.RID = vB.RID
                AND vB.Brand = 'B' LEFT JOIN
        Vals vC ON  r.RID = vC.RID
                AND vC.Brand = 'C'
```

Comment: I don't agree with your answer. Pivot is the best answer here, imagine a situation with column Brand containing the values 'A' to 'Z'. Your query wouuld grow insanely, while a pivot solution would remain almost the same

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a late entry, but here is a different approach to solve it:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Brand VARCHAR(10), Product VARCHAR(10)) 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','X ' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','XX'  
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','XXX' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B','Y'  
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B','YY'  
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'C','Z'  

SELECT [A],[B],[C] FROM (
SELECT row_number() over (partition by brand order by product) rn,  
Product, brand FROM @table
) as p
PIVOT(
  MAX(product) for Brand in ([A],[B],[C])
)as pvt
```